# Understanding a code snippet in pine script

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

I'm new to pine-script. I'm trying to understand an indicator 'HalfTrend' by Alex Orekhov (everget) at TradingView.

I'm having hard time in understanding following snippet, may you please explain this:

```
if not na(trend[1]) and trend[1] != 1
```

Does the above line mean the following:

```
na(trend[1]) //check if trend[1] exists

trend[1] != 1 //if trend[1] exists, check if it is not equal to 1
```

And not of the whole expression

In other words, are we checking if trend[1] exists and if it is equal to 1, am i right???

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your understanding is correct. `na()` will check if it is NaN. `[1]` refers to the previous value of the series.

Since it refers to a historical value with [1], for the very first bar of the chart it will return `na`. Because there is no previous value yet. That's why that check is there for.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")
trend = 0
plot(trend[1])
```

[image]